# Symfony2 asset changes

Tags: javascript, symfony, less, assetic

So it's my understanding that in the symfony dev environment assets are generated on page load through the controller if use_controller is set to true.

This is however time consuming, and pages load much faster with it set to true.
I use less and javascript and I do not want to dump my assets every change, as I'm constantly changing these files and viewing them.

I also don't want to wait the 20 seconds it takes to generate all the assets every page load.

Using assetic:dump --watch breaks my less files every time so it's pretty much useless for me, but sounds ideal. Only update what I update, great let's do that, then I can set use_controller to false and have minimal page load and have my assets updated.

**Where is the balance here?**

How can I have a fast dev env while being able to work on my assets?

Or

How can I get assetic:dump --watch to not break my css/less, as this sounds like the ideal solution. Does anyone else use less and assetic:dump --watch?

Any comments, answers, articles or advice is greatly appreciated and I know similar questions have been asked here, most pointing out to use assetic:dump --watch, which does not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know for others, but the fastest way for me to get around this issue is to have the assets stored in the `web/` directory. I know it's probably not the best way but after a couple of days searching through the net I just decided I was wasting my time.

So depending on the project, my assets go into the `web/` path. If the project is huge and has many separate bundles, I might have it both ways:

1. Store my assets in the proper `MyCompany/MyBundle/Resources/public/(images|js|css|images)` path
2. In case I have ongoing work on a specific asset(s), I temporarily change the links to point to `web/mystyle.css`
3. I create `web/mystyle.css`, do my work and then copy/paste the changes back to `MyCompany/MyBundle/Resources/public/css/mystyle.scss`

This saves me a lot of `page load` time. Usually my load time was around 4-5 seconds, which dropped to between 0.4s and 0.7s by simply placing the assets into the `web/` path. Again, I'm not pretending for this to be the best way to go, but it does the work for me. If anybody has a better way, please let me know - I would be interested as well.

Comment: So you would recommend storing in the web dir, eh? What about LESS files? Should I just let my IDE compile them and avoid dealing with symfony assetics all together, until maybe a production build is ready so they can all be minified and compiled?

Comment: That's one way to go. Another way I find myself doing is to have a `base.html.twig` template which is inherited by all other twig files and contains the paths to the assets (`{{ asset() }}`). In the `base.html.twig` put a `{% block css %}{% endblock %}` in the header. This gives you the freedom to write css as you go right from the twig template (i.e. `profile.html.twig` which extends `base.html.twig`) by simply overwriting the css block from the child. After you're done with your task, just move the code from the twig file into the proper LESS file. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. I wish I knew a place where I could read more about other people's flow and how this problem is handled by the pros. Let me know if you stumble on any articles about this.

Comment: Ahaha... you and me both. I've been searching for a more practical solution to this issue for quite some time, but without any luck. If you find anything I'd be glad to have a look as well!

Comment: What I've started doing, thanks to you, is putting the files I'm working on in /web and compiling with my IDE, and leaving everything else up to assetic with no use_controller and things are much happier in my dev environment!